# Searching a second database table if no match is found in the first

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables that follow this format:

```
       mod_site_content                  mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues      
-----------------------------    ---------------------------------------------
id | pagetitle | content         id | tmplvarid | contentid | value
-----------------------------    ---------------------------------------------
1  | Project 1 | <p> ... </p>    1  | 1         | 1         | 12.08.2014
2  | Project 2 | <p> ... </p>    2  | 1         | 2         | 13.08.2014
3  | Project 3 | <p> ... </p>    3  | 2         | 1         | <img src="..."/>
4  | Project 4 | <p> ... </p>    4  | 2         | 4         | <img src="..."/>
5  | Project 5 | <p> ... </p>    5  | 3         | 4         | [{"key":"val"...
6  | Project 6 | <p> ... </p>    6  | 3         | 5         | [{"key":"val"...
```

**mod_site_content** is a list of resources that represent webpages, and **mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues** are (optional) additional page content.

---

Let's say I want to find a string in `mod_site_content.pagetitle` or `mod_site_content.content`, but if not present, also search `mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.value` but only where `tmplvarid` is 2 or 3.

Currently, the closest I've got is with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM mod_site_content
    INNER JOIN mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues
        ON mod_site_content.id = mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.contentid
    WHERE
       tmplvarid = 2 OR
       tmplvarid = 3 AND
       pagetitle LIKE ? OR
       content LIKE ? OR
       value LIKE ?
```

But this generates a larger array of results than expected, with what appear to be a number of duplicates.

It also merges the two tables in an unexpected manner; e.g. if `Project 1` doesn't contain a match, but `id 3` in the second table does, I'd like to return `Project 1` with the result from the second table pushed into the array.

I know this question is a little verbose, but I'm attempting to be a clear as possible, knowing that my SQL knowledge is quite limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try running the below code:

```
SELECT * FROM mod_site_content
    INNER JOIN mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues
        ON mod_site_content.id = mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.contentid
    WHERE tmplvarid IN (2,3) AND 
    1= (CASE WHEN pagetitle LIKE ? OR content LIKE ? THEN 1
             WHEN value LIKE ? THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: It still returns data from mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues that don't have a tmplvarid of 2 or 3. I'd have to check closely, but the results seem very close to my attempt.

Comment: I think your first condition is matching the values present in pagetitle or content columns. In case this is happening, SQL will not go to your second condition of tmplvarid and all the values from the table mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues will show up irrespective of the value present in tmplvarid column. Can you provide the values you are passing in the where condition?

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying - the results I get all contain a valid match in pagetitle or content. It seems each resource is given a new array entry with an additional "value" key each time - irrespective of its tmplvarid. Sorry, but I'm not sure what your last question means, though. If you mean the ? placeholders, I'm using PDO bindParam().

Comment: I have edited my code based on your reply. Can you try the updated code now? Please ignore my last question in my previous comment as I got my answer.

Comment: That's much better thank you - there's no duplicates any more. Most tests seem to work fine, but when I tried searching for "outlet" (which appears in many places), I get several results back _except_ for the resource that has a pagetitle of "outlet". Barring that, this looks very promising. One other question - can you explain what the "1" in your query is for? (I assume it's a boolean).

Comment: 1 is used to match the output of case statement. You can use any value here but that should match the output of case part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59020/discussion-between-verism-and-uvgoyal).